# Moodle Redirect, change button to direct to home?

Tags: php, moodle

This is the button link:
`$dashboardurl = new moodle_url('/local/iomad_dashboard/index.php');`

I would like to change this to the home page and attempted by changing the var to:

`$dashboardurl = $CFG->wwwroot.'/'`

but no luck.

The var is used here:

```
    if (isset($data->submitandback)) {
        $dashboardurl->param('noticeok', get_string('usercreated', 'block_iomad_company_admin'));
        redirect($dashboardurl);
    } else {
        redirect($linkurl."?createdok=1");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointing to the home page (or front page) can be done declaring the following URL:

```
$homeurl = new moodle_url('/');
```

And if the dashboard is the default home page, but you want to redirect specifically on Moodle's front page, your URL should be:

```
$frontpageurl = new moodle_url('/', ['redirect' => 0]);
```

I hope I correctly understood your question.